# Change message from number_field helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following `number_field`

```
<%= f.number_field :max_rec_conteudo, { in: 1...31, class: "form-control" } %>
```

If I put a string value, it returns a error message 'Please Enter a Number'. Is there a way to change/translate that message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to check Rails I18n. Here is the guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html and particularly the chapter "5.1.1 Error Message Scopes"

in your config/locales directory you can create a `my_class.yml` file with the following content (replace those `<strings>` by what applies to you:

```
<lang_iso_code>:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        <class_name>:
          attributes:
            max_rec_conteudo:
              not_a_number: "<your translation here>"
```